# creating Database connection

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dapper

```
public class DbConnection
{         
    private static string strConnectionString;
    public string strconn;

    public static string SqlConnectionStringProp
    {
        get { return strConnectionString; }
        private set { strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MedicalConnection"].ConnectionString; }
    }
}
```

This is my `Dbconnection.cs` file

```
private IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(DbConnection.SqlConnectionStringProp);
```

this is in file `categoryDal.cs`

String is not passing from `SqlConnectionStringProp` property. 
Sql server is not connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is not being passed from `SqlConnectionStringProp` property because setter is never being called. As simple as that.

You can either convert the property to method to return connection string; OR call setter of your property somewhere; OR simply remove the setter all together and use only getter like below:

```
public static string SqlConnectionStringProp
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MedicalConnection"].ConnectionString; }
}
```